# Rank Nullity Theorem (Short Exact Sequences)

Tags: linear-algebra, exact-sequence

In the book Manifolds, Tensors and Forms, there is the following theorem:

We have a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \ker T\xrightarrow{\iota} V\xrightarrow{T} W\rightarrow 0$ where $\iota$ is the inclusion mapping and $T$ is surjective. If $S$ is a section of $T$, then $V=\ker T \oplus S(W)$.

In the proof, we want to show that $\ker T\cap S(W)=\{0\}$. To do so, he notes that $S$ is injective. Then he says that we have a unique $w\in W$ such that $S(w)=x$, and then using the fact that $S$ is a section we can conclude that $w=T\circ S(w)=T(x)=0$, and from the linearity of $S$ we must have $x=0$.

Now, this is all fine, but here's my question: why do we need the fact that $S$ is injective? Rephrased, why do we need that $w$ is unique? As far as I can tell, the argument doesn't depend on it, but only on the fact that $S$ is linear and that $S:W\to S(W)$ is surjective.

Comment: You're absolutely right, the argument doesn't depend on injectivity of $S$ at all. I imagine that the author, having already observed along the way that $S$ is injective, figured that they'd might as well acknowledge this fact in the remainder of the proof of the theorem.

Comment: I actually made a minor mistake in stating my question, since he does use the injectivity of $S$ to conclude that $W$ and $S(W)$ are isomorphic so that he can state $\dim V=\dim\ker T +\dim W$, with $W$ replacing $S(W)$. So really it's just the observation that $w$ is unique that's unnecessary, and I think you're right that he's just acknowledging it because he can.